# How to build a path to a Firestore document in security rules using variables

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm writing a rule to allow the creation of new document to My_Collection whose structure looks like this:

```
field1="value-1"
field2="value-2"
field3="other-miscellaneous-values"
```

This should be allowed only if there is no document in Side_Collection with a document ID using the following format:

```
value-1:value-2
```

Where "value-1" comes from the document field "field1", and "value-2" comes from "field2", and they are delimited with a colon.

Here is the rule I am trying:

```
allow create: if !exists(/{database}/Side_Collection/{request.resource.data.field1}:{request.resource.data.field2});
```

And this is the kind of error messages I get:

```
Error saving rules - Line 24: Unexpected '}'.; Line 24: Missing 'match' keyword before path.; Line 24: Unexpected '.'.; Line 24: mismatched input 'request' expecting '}'; Line 24: Unexpected ':'.; Line 24: Unexpected ')'.; Line 30: Unexpected 'match'.
```

I tried a few variations of the above, but nothing works.

Comment: OK. The editing of the post is good. But the comments are gone. And the problem is still there. I am reading this https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions, but still have some questions.

Comment: One problem is that when I try to insert the colon, I always get an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to insert some variable value or expression inside a path construction, you have to use `$()` to isolate that expression.  This is discussed in the documentation for [accessing other documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents).

In your case, you probably want to build the path to pass to exists() like this (I added carriage returns for readability, you will want to remove them):

```
exists(
  /databases
  /$(database)
  /documents
  /Side_Collection
  /$(request.resource.data.field1 + ":" + request.resource.data.field2);
```